# lateinit property has not been initialized when using @Autowired

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

I'm using @Bean and @Autowired

```
@Component
class ConfigurationServiceInvoker()  {

    fun getRules(request: RulesRequest): RulesResponse {
        return runBlocking { stub.geRules(request) }
    }
}
```

```
@Component
object InvokerConfiguration {
    
    @Bean
    fun getConfigurationServiceInvoker(): ConfigurationServiceInvoker {
        return ConfigurationServiceInvoker()
    }
}
```

When I calling getRules() function I got error "lateinit property configurationServiceInvoker has not been initialized", how to fix this issue?

```
@Autowired
private lateinit var configurationServiceInvoker: ConfigurationServiceInvoker

val response = configurationServiceInvoker.getRules()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`configurationServiceInvoker.getRules()` is being invoked during construction of the object. Runtime annotation processors like that which handles @Autowired occur after the object is constructed. Consider using `@PostConstruct` to initialize the response value, like so:

```
@Autowired
private lateinit var configurationServiceInvoker: ConfigurationServiceInvoker

lateinit var response;

@PostConstruct
fun postConstruct() {
    response = configurationServiceInvoker.getRules()
}
```

Comment: I'm not that understand, where do I need to put @PostConstruct?

Comment: Added usage example. You can google @PostConstruct for piles of usage examples